# Compound distribution

Tags: r, probability, distributions, expectation-maximization, compound-distributions

I'm trying to compute a maximum likelihood of compound Poisson exponential distribution in R by using EM-algorithm method. The distribution is defined by $∑N_j=1 Y_j$ where $Y_n$ is i.i.d sequence independent exp(θ) values and N is a Poisson distribution with parameter β and truncated at 0. I'm trying to estimate this parameters θ and β without luck.

Comment: You need to post what you have and let people know where you are stuck, otherwise it really is not a question.

Comment: A fixed sum of independent exponential distributions is gamma-distribution. Use this fact when conditioning on N.